# Why to use Model from MVC in frontend?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, frontend, thymeleaf

I've done almost all of my web projects using Java(Spring MVC + Thymeleaf) and it's MVC technologies. Recently I've heared about REST and started learning some stuff about it. I realized that it is one of the coolest things I've ever seen in my whole life!(I'm just joking around, it's definitely not)

All we need is just to parse data to json type and then return it to the frontend. And in frontend we no longer need to use Model and it's objects. Frontend can get all required data in nice-to-work-with json type using one single GET request!

We don't need to use some weird Thymeleaf constructions to handle errors or to iterate through the list in our template! We can handle all events and process all data using javascript and it's frameworks. It is much more powerful.

Does there exist something I missed? When to use Model? When to use json-type data?

Answer (score 2):

These are two (somewhat overlapping) approaches to frontend development: generating pages on the backend and on the frontend.

Using a backend model and Thymeleaf templates (or any other HTML templates), you generate your web page on the server side. This means the following benefits

- you can write frontend and backend logic in one language (Java);
- you can enforce data and security constraints in one place - on the backend, using Java code or configuration;
- in many cases, it's faster for the user to get their first page, since the rendering happens on the server, and the user gets an already rendered page;

But this approach has the following drawbacks:

- the server has to render the pages, which means more load on the server;
- most of the modern web sites and applications use JavaScript anyway, so you'll have to write at least some JavaScript;
- server-generated pages don't even come close to what's possible to render in the browser.

Providing a REST API for a JavaScript frontend, you have the following benefits:

- you unload your server, since most of the UI related work happens on the user's device;
- you can achieve much more with modern frontend frameworks;
- navigating on an already rendered UI is faster, since you don't need for the server to render every page, you only need to get a relatively small JSON response and then update the page dynamically.

But this approach has the following tradeoffs:

- the user generally waits longer to see their first page, as the browser needs to download a lot of scripts and then spend time on dynamic rendering of the page;
- in a large application, you need to either have a full-stack developer team, or two teams working on frontend and backend separately;
- you have to write your UI logic in JavaScript. Make of it what you will :)
- you have to sometimes duplicate the constraints both on the frontend and on the backend: e.g., if a user can't edit a field, you have to both show it as read-only on the frontend, and add validation in your REST service, since the user may try to access your REST API directly and bypass the frontend validation;
- you have to be more aware of securing your REST API in general.